# Unexpected query results with DSE Java Driver

Tags: datastax-enterprise, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I’m getting unexpected results using the DSE Java Driver with the query below:

```
List<Object> results = DseGraph.traversal(session).V()
.has("name", "marko").out("knows").values("name")
.toBulkSet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I expected the returned List to contain 2 items of type `String` in the list being “vadas” and “josh”,
But instead it’s returning a list with 2 items of type `LinkedHashMap` with first item with key as `result` and the value as `vadas` and second item as key as `result` and the value as `josh`.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `dse-java-driver-core` `1.2.3` returns the results in `LinkedHashMap`. Whereas `1.4.0` returns `List` of `String`.